# How can I activate the active bar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I disabled the active bar in Visual Studio Code and now I can no longer activate. How can I reactivate it?

[image: Example image with hidden active bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the **View** menu. Then choose **Show Activity Bar**. That's it!